# How to cycle through images with button clicks using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some images that I want to cycle through using previous/next buttons.

The image is supposed to be dynamic through angular. So if you click one of the buttons it should display a different image in the array of images that I have in the controller.

Here is essentially what I tried:

HTML -

```
<div>
    <md-button ng-click="switchImage(-1)"> Prev Image </md-button>
    <img ng-src="assets/img/{{image}}"/>
    <md-button ng-click="switchImage(1)"> Next Image </md-button>
</div>
```

Javascript/Angular -

```
// Character image selection array
var self = this;
self.images = ['image1.gif', 'image2.gif', 'image3.gif', 'image4.gif'];
self.index = 0;
$scope.image = self.images[self.index]; // Display the first image

function switchImage(step) {
  self.index += step;
  $scope.image = self.images[self.index];
};
```

Any suggestions on what is the better way to do this?

The way I have it now does not change the image when I click the buttons. I made sure to put a breakpoint into the switchImage function and it does not go into it when I click the buttons.

Comment: this should work... what's the problem u r facing?

Comment: at least until you get to end of array. Need to validate `self.index += step;` and adjust accordingly

Comment: @A.B. This code did not work for some reason. I am wondering what was wrong with it. If I click a button the image does not change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking about the edge case i.e. when the index size reaches 0 or 4 then you can modify your code like this:

(Also, you need to register that function in the `$scope`)

```
$scope.switchImage = function(step) {
  self.index += step;

  // When user keeps clicking next image and index crosses end of array
  if (self.index == self.images.length) {
     // reset to zero
     self.index = 0;
  } else if (self.index < 0) {
     // else if user keeps clicking previous image and index goes negative
     // reset to the last image
     self.index = self.images.length - 1;
  }

  $scope.image = self.images[self.index];
};
```

Comment: what is `size()`?

Comment: Oops!! accidently used the `size()` of Java

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal I am asking how to make the image cycling work. Currently my way of doing it does not even go into the switchImage function